# use baseUrl from CLI instead of protractor config

Tags: protractor, angular-cli

I am using angular CLI 7 and protractor 5.4.2. 
I want my protractor tests to use the `baseUrl` from CLI instead of protractor config.
I have tried the below.

```
ng e2e --base-url="https://google.com"
```

Only to see :

```
Option "baseUrl" is deprecated: Use "baseUrl" in the Protractor config file instead.
The 'baseUrl' option cannot be used with 'devServerTarget'.
When present, 'devServerTarget' will be used to automatically setup 'baseUrl' for Protractor.
Error: The 'baseUrl' option cannot be used with 'devServerTarget'.
When present, 'devServerTarget' will be used to automatically setup 'baseUrl' for Protractor.
    at ProtractorBuilder.run
```

Any body who experienced this before ? How can I use the baseUrl otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following trick and it worked for me :

I updated my angular.json file and added a new parameter `configurations`

```
"e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/local.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "env": {
              "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractorconf.js",
              "devServerTarget": ""
            }
          }
        },
```

It works when I run

```
ng e2e -c env --baseUrl="https://google.com"
```

-c is the configurations specified in angular.json.

Refer to https://angular.io/cli/e2e for more options

Answer (score 2):

Try this, for me, it works.

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --params.baseUrl 'https://google.com'
```